# Socket.io on FF 11 and Chrome 18.0?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am having some issues with websockets and socket.io.

On localhost, socket.io seems to work ok but when I push to production on no.de, on FF 11 and Chrome 18.0, it takes forever to connect and after about 5 seconds the connection is lost and not reestablished. It works fine on Safari. This is with and without configuring the transports with websocket included.

When I configure the transports without 'websocket', all is well, connections are quick and not dropped. So I have it working now, but not as I would like it to.

Two things I am confused on:
- I thought these browser versions supported websockets.
- I thought socket.io would default to the next best transport solution.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that No.de servers don't proxy correctly. I don't know the details. I've found the info here:

http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=30975

You won't get the job done unless you pay! As always. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Guess I could have dug deeper to find that one. At least others who don't find the answer might get the link from here?